# Object.assign assigns datestring to type Date in model

Tags: typescript, angular5

I'm having trouble understanding why my model doesn't throw an error and instead freely assigned the datestring I get from the httpClient call to the Date type in my model.

Here is the code

```js
// Data model
export class Data {
  purpose: string = null;
  percentSold: number = null;
  originalTerm: number = null;
  originatedBy: string = null;
  noteDate: Date = null;
  productType: string = null;
  maturityDate: Date = null;
  noteAmount: number = null;
  disburseDate: Date = null;
  interestRate: number = null;
  number: number = null;
  branch: string = null;
  principal: number = null;
  amountAdvanced: number = null;
  code: Code;
  mailingAddress: AccountAddress;

  constructor() {
    this.code = new Code();
    this.mailingAddress = new AccountAddress();
  }
}

let data = new Data();
Object.assign(data, someObjectFromRouteCall);

// data object from Data model has noteDate and disimburseDate still be of type string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment happens during runtime where TypeScript is not active. It does type checking only during compilation.

You have two choices:

- Do the type checks/conversions manually by the means of JavaScript.
- Use exactly the same types on server and client sides. This can be easily achieved if you choose TypeScript as your backend language, but should also be possible with other backend languages as long as there are class/interface autogenerators available for the language of your choice. But to benefit from that approach you need to go without `Date` objects and deal with date strings instead.

Comment: ok so what i want to understand is whether I have no choice but to manually turn each and every datestring into Date object inside the constructor

Comment: Yes unfortunately you have no choice. But you could consider avoiding `Date` objects and stick with date/time/date+time strings. Though `Date` objects offer benefits, they make things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: here's my follow up question, because with the new ngx bootstrap, they only accept Date objects as input for their Date fields, is there a quicker way of bypassing this process instead of the manual way?

Here is the documentation for the DatePicker module: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: I know that the standard type for date/time related controls is `Date`. But probably some of them accept date strings as alternative values. I am not sure about that. If the control of your choice is not that flexible, just provide it with a `new Date(yourDateString)` to make it happy. Of course you need to find a way of converting it back to a date string when saving the form.

Comment: Unfortunately things like that are not really thought through by the makers of web technologies.

Comment: Still I am interested what other people think about this topic.